# Complex coordinate plane: what does it look like?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, coordinate-systems

I've read about the complex coordinate plane(stemming from one of my preceding problems) and i have a question on it: where would a coordinate (say, $(a+bi, c+di)$) go on the 4-D complex coordinate plane?

Comment: If you have a 4-D Euclidean space, you can do the identification $(a+bi,c+di) \to (a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{R}^4$, so that would be where it goes.